# How to draw polyline on OpenStreetMap with the help of array object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to draw polyline on OpenStreetMap with the help of marker array object
currently I am selected all marker(longitude, latitude) values from database and on that marker basis, I want to draw polyline for showing route of the particular user.

```
[window.onload = function GetOSMMap() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("dvMap");
    var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); // Transform from WGS 1984
    var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection                                                                                            
    var zoom = 15;
    map.addLayer(mapnik);

    var marker = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");

    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers\[i\]
        var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(data.lng, data.lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());

        map.addLayer(marker);
        marker.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));
        map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom);

    }
    var lineLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Line Layer");

    map.addLayer(lineLayer);
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(lineLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path));
    var points = new Array(
        new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(data.lng, data.lat)
    );
    points.push(lonLat);
    var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points);

    var style = {
        strokeColor: '#0000ff',
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeWidth: 5
    };

    var lineFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(line, null, style);
    lineLayer.addFeatures(\[lineFeature\]);

}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Change array variable declaration create simple object of array
var points = new Array(
        new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(data.lng, data.lat)
    );  to 
var points = new Array();
2) Change in points.push(lonLat); to
 points.push(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(data.lng,data.lat)); and pass write this line under marker for loop.
3) Add one line extra
line.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));